# How to find max value in ilnumerics symetric matrix?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I have an ilnumerics symetric matrix of double like that

```
100        90,38000   87,27000   44,23000   34,62000   30,77000 
90,38000        100   90,91000   34,62000   44,23000   34,62000 
87,27000   90,91000        100   36,36000   38,18000   47,27000 
34,62000   44,23000   38,18000   89,80000        100   90,38000 
30,77000   34,62000   47,27000   86,54000   90,38000        100
```

I want to find maximum value. I use

```
ILNumerics.ILRetArray<double> maxValue = ILNumerics.ILMath.maxall(matrixSimilarity);
```

The result is maxValue = 100. 
I want result without taking the values ​​on the diagonal => maxValue = 90,91

How can do this with ilnumerics function in C#?

Comment: Keep an eye on your variable declaration. You basically will only use ILArray<T>. ILRetArray is used in function declarations only. See: http://ilnumerics.net/GeneralRules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be faster ways to the result, but this would work:

```
ILArray<double> E = counter(5, 5);
```

E is now:

```
<Double> [5,5]
    [0]:          1          6         11         16         21 
    [1]:          2          7         12         17         22 
    [2]:          3          8         13         18         23 
    [3]:          4          9         14         19         24 
    [4]:          5         10         15         20         25
```

Copy to a new variable, modify the diagonal and acquire the maximum value:

```
// make a copy of E
ILArray<double> maxE = E.C; 
// set diagonal of the copy to smallest value
maxE[r(0,maxE.S[0]+1,numel(maxE)-1)] = minall(maxE); 
// compute the max value 
maxE = maxall(maxE); 

>maxE 
<Double>         24
```

Note, the code is expected to get executed in the context of a subclass of ILMath, as usual.